# PDF transparent background disappears in PowerPoint

Tags: pdf, background, powerpoint

A PDF that I used previously in a Latex Beamer presentation has a transparent background. Yet when I put it in a PowerPoint presentation, it shows up with the white background. How can I fix it to have transparent background in PPT, as well?

Comment: To be more helpful, can we downvote with an explanation why one does not like the question?

Answer (score 0):

In PowerPoint, you can use "Format Background" to set the transparency in the option "Solid fill", "Picture or texture fill" and "Gradient fill".